# SQL to Excel Export, today's data gives Excel error regarding corruption/file extension

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, vb.net

OK I have a large application and I am using this same procedure to provide output from many tables throughout, with no problems.

I am using `closedxml.excel` and the below procedure - with a Query of course.

In one particular table that collects machine data, I can query many date ranges but if I include today I get an error from excel.
[image: My Error]

The table consists `os a datetime field 2 nvarchar(20)` and a bunch of floats. I looked through the the `textfields` for odd characters and can't find anything.

If anyone could give me a direction to look in it would be great.
Here is my code example.

```vb
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        Using wb As New XLWorkbook()
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Query Results")
                            Response.Clear()
                            Response.Buffer = True
                            Response.Charset = ""
                            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xls")
                            Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
                                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
                                Response.Flush()
                                Response.End()
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'IO.File.AppendAllText("/WO_Error_Logs/Log.txt", String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Environment.NewLine, Date.Now(), Environment.NewLine, ex.Message))
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "TimeError3", "TimeError3();", True)
    End Try
```

Comment: 1st thing to do is open the file in a text editor to make sure its not a textual  server error response.

Comment: I did the query in sql and pasted the results in notepad. There are 35,000 rows, but I spent quite a bit of time looking at it to no avail.

Comment: I mean look inside *sqlexport (1).xlsx*

Comment: If it's working for most data sets and failing on one particular table, then the reasonable conclusion is that there is almost certainly some kind of data problem -- a hidden character or improperly created tag that is making it impossible to parse the generated XML.  If you can't find it by interrogating the file as text, then start modifying your sql cmd to bring back smaller subsets and try to hone in on the offending row.

Comment: Well that was tedious, I was hoping for an easier way but that darn record 13206 was crashing excel. It had a partial partnumber and an empty string in on text field, but nothing suspicious. either way I deleted it and all is well. Thanks @Greenspark I needed a push.